# How can I get the difference in the two dates in js which are in string?

Tags: javascript, json, date, ecmascript-6

I have a certain format which is in the

```
{
    "updatedAt": "2022-01-04 22:41:32.268897",
    "status": "open",
    "createdAt": "2022-01-04 22:41:26.328339"
}
```

I want to get the difference in hours or minutes of both the dates I tried many but didn't get the expected result.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Date module in javascript.

```
const obj = { "updatedAt": "2022-01-04 22:41:32.268897", "status": "open", "createdAt": "2022-01-03 22:41:26.328339" };

const updatedAt = new Date(obj.updatedAt);
const createdAt = new Date(obj.createdAt);

const diffInMilliSecs = updatedAt - createdAt;
```

This difference is in milliseconds. You can now convert this into seconds or minutes or hours.

Comment: Re `new Date(obj.updatedAt)`, see [*Why does Date.parse give incorrect results?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/why-does-date-parse-give-incorrect-results) "2022-01-04 22:41:32.268897" is not a format supported by ECMA-262 so parsing is implementation dependent. It produces an invalid Date in Safari at least.